# Finding line equation given equation of two planes

Tags: linear-algebra

> $l$ is the intersection line between two planes $P_1=2x-3y+z-1=0$ and $P_2=x-y+z=0$ find the plane equation

---

I solved the equation assuming $z=0$ as a free variable to find a point on the line and got $x-2y=1$ so a possible solution will be $(2,1,0)$ and the direction vector of the line is perpendicular to the normals of the plane so we get $\vec s \perp \vec n_1$ and $\vec s \perp \vec n_2$ and from here $\vec s= \vec n_1 \times \vec n_2=(2,1,-1) $

so my line equation is $l=(2,1,0)+t(2,1,-1)$ or $\frac{x-2}{2}=\frac{y-1}{1}=\frac{z-0}{-1}$

but apparently this is wrong the point in the book is  $(1,0,-1)$ and the equation is $\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y-0}{1}=\frac{z+1}{-1}$

I can't figure what am I doing wrong.. thakns for any help and tips

Comment: $(2,1,0)$ is not a solution of $x-2y=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $y=0$ gives one point $(1,0,-1)$ on the line $(L)$ of intersection.
The direction ratio of the $(L)$ is given by the cross product of their normals as
$$
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \\
2 & -3 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right|=-2 \vec{i}-\vec{j}+\vec{k}
$$
Therefore the equation of $(L)$ is
$$
\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y}{1}=\frac{z+1}{-1}
$$

Comment: what if i set $z=0$? I would get $(-1,-1,0)$ as a possible solution for $x-2y=1$ and it would still show my solution is wrong why is it right only if $y=0$?